# GDAL viewshed does not start

Tags: qgis, viewshed, library

I am trying to start a viewshed analysis on the current LTR QGIS version (3.22.15) on MacOS Ventura 13.2. The installation of QGIS is the plain vanilla package as downloaded from qgis.org. However it fails to start viewshed indicating it is missing a library. The statement it throws says:

```
*dyld[17907]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgdal.28.dylib
Referenced from: <C9C36A19-0A99-3DEF-B70E-7D4EE182184C> /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/_gdal_viewshed
Reason: tried: '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/libgdal.28.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.28.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgdal.28.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/run_gdal_binary.bash: line 13: 17907 Abort trap: 6 "$THISDIR/_$ALGNAME" "$@"
Process returned error code 134*
```

For the full output of the processing window see picture below.

Now - what am I missing to be able to perform the function? How do I make QGIS find the needed library? Is it just a problem of the path or is the default installation lacking something?
[image: Log of viewshed]

Comment: Can you run any GDAL DEM algorithm, for example slope?

Comment: Yes, GDAL slope runs perfectly well, so does hillshade, etc.

Comment: In that case there may a a bug that affects only viewshed. I would write mail to qgis-users mailing list.